# Is it always my fault when Android app crash with Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I made my first game with Unity3D, which is an Android app. I get 170k downloads for 1 month, and there are some crash I can see on Google Play Developer Console.

[image]

some crash comes from script I never touch, so I'm asking myself, is this is really **my fault**, or Unity, or Android fault ?

[image]

You can see this crash only happen on **Android 5.1 on Galaxy**.

I suppose, there are no **way to fix that** ? (I think 11 crashes for 170k downloads is not significant, but **I prefer to know** if there is something to do)

Thanks.

Comment: It could be your fault or Unity's fault... Where is the script that crashes? Where is the crash log?

Comment: None come from my script. There are error from libc.so, dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass, lib/arm/libunity.so...